# getting null path while uploading image upload in .net

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, updatepanel

I have used file upload control of asp.net but I am getting empty string while saving.my code-

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fuProductLogo" runat="server" CssClass="file paddBottom5px"  />
```

.cs code is-

```
if (fuProductLogo.PostedFile != null && fuProductLogo.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
                {
...
}
```

but the .PstedFile and .CountLength is coming zero but the same code is working fine in another page.Please help.

Comment: condition is wrong.Put proper brackets

Comment: is your fileupload placed in an updatepanel?

Comment: @zod can you tell me where I have placed the brackets wrong

Comment: @Will yes it is in update update panel. Does it make any difference?

Comment: if ((fuProductLogo.PostedFile != null) && (fuProductLogo.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0))

Comment: Oh Zod that doesn't make any difference. that is the same thing.thanks for you effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the FileUpload is in an UpdatePanel it will be cleared on each ajax-postback. You can use multiple UpdatePanels around the FileUpload control and keep the FileUpload out of them. Also make sure that the button that triggers the actual upload does a real postback, not an asyncpostback. Do this by adding the button to the PostbackTrigger of it's UpdatePanel or by taking it out of the UpdatePanel.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Submit" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

You can also use an [AsyncFileUpload](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/asyncfileupload/asyncfileupload.aspx) control from the Asp.net Ajax Toolkit, it works inside an UpdatePanel but it is a little harder to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things to check here:

- as @williem said, remove updatepanel from the form if you are using it
- add `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` in the form tag

Please remember to update your post after your code modifications and checks.

Comment: the whole page is inside the update panel how can I put outside? and there is not form tag in my aspx code.

Comment: well, you cannot use update panels while uploading a form.
 if you are using master page, your form tag will be there